# match a pattern and select specific lines in a file

Tags: python

I have a text file displayed below. I would like to select 2 lines (line 1 and line 2) under the Class 10 block only.

```
Thu May 29 14:16:00 PDT 2014
Class 09
line 0
line 1
line 2
--
Class 10
line 0
line 1
line 2
--
Class 11
line 0
line 1
line 2
--
Thu May 29 14:20:00 PDT 2014
Class 09
line 0
line 1
line 2
--
Class 10
line 0
line 1
line 2
--
Class 11
line 0
line 1
line 2
--
```

I have tried the following, but `linecache` grabs line 1 only. I would like to find a way to grab line1 first then line2. any idea?
Thanks

```
numOflines = sum(1 for line in open('text.txt'))
print(num_lines)
for i in range(start,numOflines,step):  
    linea = linecache.getline('text.txt', i)
    print linea
```

Comment: what is `linecache`?  to calculate `numOflines` you're already looping over the whole file once.  You should only need to do a single pass over the file.

Comment: I think it's this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html

Comment: Thanks!  I've never heard of it before.  Interesting...

Comment: Is this a larger file or something that fits into memory?

Answer (score 1):

```
numOflines = sum(1 for line in open('text.txt'))
```

This line counts the lines in the file and that's it. Probably not what you want.

Not sure why you'd want `linecache`. And you don't show how you compute `start` or `step`, which is probably where your bug is.

What you want probably would look something like this:

```
def reading_function():
    searching = True
    linesToRead = 2
    with open('text.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if searching and line.strip() == "Class 10":
                searching = False
            elif not searching:
                print line.strip()
                linesToRead -= 1
                if linesToRead == 0:
                    return
```

Answer (score 1):

Just playing around.

I don't think you should need flags and manipulation of counters, just some lovely loops.

```
lines_after_text = 2
search_text = "Class 10"
desired_lines = [] # in case search_text appears in text.txt more than once.
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if search_text in line:
            desired_lines.extend([next(f) for i in range(lines_after_text)])
```

Comment: I have tried it. it never get to the if block:lines_after_text = 2
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print("Before if")
        if "Class 10" in line:
            print(" Entered the if")
            desired_lines = [f.next() for i in range(lines_after_text)]
            print (line)
            break
        else:
            print("out of the if statement")

Comment: Works fine here.  You might want to check your file, "text.txt", to make sure it actually contains the expected search text.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget a regex!

```
with open(fn) as f:
    for m in re.finditer(r'^(Class 10.*?)(?:^Class 11|\Z)', f.read(), re.M | re.S):
        print m.group(1).splitlines()[2:4]
```

Prints:

```
['line 1', 'line 2']
['line 1', 'line 2']
```

If the file is larger than what you want in memory, use a memory map:

```
import re
import mmap

with open(fn) as f:
    mm=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0,access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for m in re.finditer(r'^(Class 10.*?)(?:^Class 11|\Z)', mm, re.M | re.S):
        print m.group(1).splitlines()[2:4]
```